# Кавычки в запросе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите разобратся с экранированием. Пытаюсь сделать 'динамический запрос из базы'. Т.е. имеем 2 таблицы, пользователи и локация. Если юзер при поиске указал город - учитываем это в запросе, если не ввёл - не учитываем и делаем запрос без фильтра по городу. Вот только никак не могу с кавычками разобратся. То они мешают друг другу, то не парсятся.. Как быть?

```
if(isset($_POST['plusLocation'])){  //если юзер указал город
    $thisCity=strip_tags($_POST['plusLocation']);
    $loc='AND l.city=$thisCity';    //в динамической переменной спрашиваем город
}else{
    $loc='';   //иначе делаем запрос без города
}

$query="SELECT * FROM table1 t
    INNER JOIN location l ON l.id=t.id
    WHERE t.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 $loc";   //и подставляем в конец или город или ничего
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['plusLocation']))
$loc="AND l.city='$thisCity'";    //в динамической переменной спрашиваем город
```

Answer (score 1):

для вашего случая нужно воспользоваться

```
$thisCity = mysql_real_escape_string($thisCity);
```

ну а лучше, быстрей и безопасней переходить на [PDO](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) и пользоваться плейсхолдерами.

**upd** и как верно заметил @Nord001

```
$loc="AND l.city='$thisCity'";
```

Comment: Там ещё ошибка в
$loc='AND l.city=$thisCity';    //в динамической переменной спрашиваем город

Comment: @Nord001 вполней возможен вариант что передается id города, но вы правы, кавычки не помешают.

Comment: @FLK
Там одинарные ковычки и PHP туда ничего не подставит а оставит как есть

Comment: @Nord001 действительно, не обратил внимания. спасибо